# Cannot sftp using a password

Tags: ssh, sftp, user-management

I have setup my server to allow sftp using a password however I'm getting `Authentication failed.` even though I'm using the correct password. Here is my `sshd_config`

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l DEBUG3

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

# Begin SFTP-Server block
Match Group www-data
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
# End SFTP-Server block
```

As you can notice at the last line under `Match Group` I have set `PasswordAuthentication yes` I've also made sure that my user is part of `www-data` however I still couldn't login using a password. I can SSH without password but I deliberately removed my keys on the server to test if I can `sftp` with just the password OR the keys need to be in the `authorized_keys` to be able to login besides the password? I've also made sure that I restarted the SSH service to apply the changes. What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT

And here's the log on my `FileZilla`:

```
Status:         Connecting to clone-stage-wplogic-net...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=4
Command:    open "dummyuser@clone-stage-wplogic-net" 22
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Error:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Could not connect to server
Status:         Waiting to retry...
Status:         Connecting to clone-stage-wplogic-net...
```

Here is the content of my `/var/log/auth.log` file:

```
Jun 28 02:47:47 clone-stage-wplogic-net sshd[18017]: error: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
Jun 28 02:47:55 clone-stage-wplogic-net sshd[18019]: error: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

Comment: SFTP needs the sftp binary on the target host to work. Does the user you log in with have access to that binary?

Comment: @Johan if you use `internal-sftp`, you don't need the binary in `chroot`.

Comment: @Johan how do I know if the user has access to that binary?

Comment: @Jakuje when you use `internal-sftp` does that mean it's using the default binary for sftp on the server?

Comment: @Jakuje You are correct sir :) Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: @JohnnyQ What di the logs say? Probably in /var/log/messages

Comment: @Johan I've updated my post. Please see the logs at the edit part.

Comment: Set up more verbose logging on the server `LogLevel DEBUG3` and post all relevant logs to your session.

Comment: @JohnnyQ Hmm.. Does the output for: $ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes localhost and $ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes dummyuser@localhost differ?

Comment: @Johan I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` looks like the sftp server is requiring me to have an ssh key?

Comment: @Jakuje actually that's the log level I have with my sftp settings: `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l DEBUG3`

Comment: I said in the `sshd_config`, not in the Subsystem. What are the new messages you see in the log?

Comment: @Jakuje ah yes that config was from my `sshd_config` file. The same info I pasted above is what I see on the `/var/log/auth.log`. I also made sure that I restarted the SSH service.

Answer (score 4):

This is the relevant line from the log file:

```
Jun 28 02:03:04 clone-stage-wplogic-net sshd[16608]: Invalid user oracle from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

So, the user oracle is not allowed to connect. The next question is of course why this user is considered invalid, and the answer probably lies here:

```
Match Group www-data
```

So, add the user `oracle` to the group `www-data`.

Comment: Thanks but I think that's a bot who's trying to connect and not related to any of the users I'm trying to login with. Let me update the logs again. sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnnyQ It would be very helpful if you would include logs that are actually relevant to your question instead of some random unrelated log files, yes.